# how to use Author attribute in nunit test cases

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit-3.0

I want to access Nunit Author attribute and fetch author value in setup method.
Please let me know the correct way of doing it.

Below is the way i tried accessing "Author" attribute,but getting null value in return.
It is giving me exception Object reference not set to instance of object.

```
[TestFixture]
    public class EPTestFlow : MerlinBase
    {

        [Test]
        [Property(PropertyNames.Author,"Kalyani")]
        [TestCaseSource(typeof(TestDataMerlin), "LoginDetails", new object[] { new string[] { "TC01"} })]
        public void PatientEnrollment(string userDetails, LoginDetails loginDetails)
        {

        }
     }
```

```
        [SetUp]
        public void TestInitialize()
        {
           var testAuthor = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties[PropertyNames.Author];
            string name = testAuthor.ToString();
        }
```

Updated with suggested approach:

```
        [Test]
        [Author("Kalyani")]
        [TestCaseSource(typeof(TestDataMerlin), "LoginDetails", new object[] { new string[] { "TC01"} })]
        public void PatientEnrollment(string userDetails, LoginDetails loginDetails)
        {
        }
```

```
[TearDown]
        public void TestCleanup()
        {
            //IList testAuthor = (IList)TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties["Author"];
            //foreach (string author in testAuthor)
            //{
            //    string name12 = author.ToString();
            //}
            //string name = testAuthor.ToString();

            var category = (string)TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties.Get("Author");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting null value for 'PropertyNames.Author' because you are trying to access the Author property before setting it.

Since SetUp is executed before each Test method the value of Author is null in SetUp method. You can get the Author value in the 'TearDown' method and use it in the logs(Assuming you are trying to use the author value for some logging).

You can read more about the Nunit attributes [here](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Attributes)

Try setting author attribute like below in Test method

```
 [Test]
 [Author("Author_Name")]
 public void TestTest() { /* ... */ }
}
```

and retrieve using below in TearDown method

```
var category = (string) TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties.Get("Author");
```

If you are using TestCaseSource attribute then use the below to set the Author property in Test method

```
        [Test]        
        [TestCaseSource(typeof(TestDataMerlin), "LoginDetails", new object[] { new string[] { "TC01"} })]
        public void PatientEnrollment(string userDetails, LoginDetails loginDetails)
        {                      
        TestExecutionContext.CurrentContext.CurrentTest.Properties.Add("Author", "Author_Name");
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TestCleanup()
        {
            string name = TestExecutionContext.CurrentContext.CurrentTest.Properties.Get("Author").ToString();
        }
```

Comment: I tried accessing author attribute in teardown, but now it is returning me 0 value.

Comment: [TearDown]
        public void TestCleanup()
        {
            IList testAuthor = (IList)TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties["Author"];
            foreach (string author in testAuthor)
            {
                string name12 = author.ToString();
            }

Comment: Edited answer according to comment. Please check.

Comment: i tried using the solution you provided, but still getting null value in return. Since i am using TestCaseSource attribute, thinking if this attribute is causing trouble.

Comment: please check above question with "Updated with suggested approach:"

Comment: just encountered that since i am using TestCaseSource Attribute, i cannot access Author attribute. I tried commenting testcasesource attribute and Author value was retrieved. But since my test flow requires testcasesource attribute, checking if there any way to handle it.

Comment: Updated the answer with "TestCaseSource" case. Let me know if it works out for you.

Comment: thanks for the solution, but i don't want name and author to be static. As there are different members in team, Each one will develop resp testcase, so for each test i want to assign author - like who created script

Comment: you can still set the author for individual test method using "   TestExecutionContext.CurrentContext.CurrentTest.Properties.Add("Author", "Author_Name");
" which I have specified in the end of the answer

Comment: it worked for me, thanks for you help. but thinking on otherside, ideally setting of property should happen at test level, not before starting script/flow of test. I am thinking in direction if test standard is maintained, then any new member in team can flow that and wont forget to add category. Now in this case chances of missing to add property is high.